# Calculation of the average of the values of a column in a matrix

Tags: matrix

I am trying to have a list of values which corresponds to the mean of the values of each column of a matrix. Here I show a quick example (my current matrix has a dimension of 1000 * 1000)

If I have matrix like this:
matrixExample = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 9, 9, 9}}
I would have to obtain a list like this:
mean values={5, 5.7, 6.3, 7}.

Answer (score 6):

```
matrixExample = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 9, 9, 9}};
Mean[matrixExample]
(*    {5, 17/3, 19/3, 7}    *)
% // N
(*    {5., 5.66667, 6.33333, 7.}    *)
```